# Why does this slight change make bash crash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have been playing around with a script that uses a "binary" approach to finding the number of .txt files in a directory. The script optionally takes a guess ($1) as a point of departure.

The script, named "search.sh" is mostly simple maths:

```
#!/bin/bash

set_SEARCH()
{
    DIVIDED=$SEARCH
    SEARCH=$(($SEARCH * 2))
}

increase_SEARCH()
{
    SEARCH=$(($SEARCH + $DIVIDED))
    DIVIDED=$(($DIVIDED / 2))
    #echo $DIVIDED
}

decrease_SEARCH()
{
    SEARCH=$(($SEARCH - $DIVIDED))
    DIVIDED=$(($DIVIDED / 2))
    #echo $DIVIDED
}

test_SEARCH()
{
    while [ -f "$(($SEARCH * 2)).txt" ]
    do
        set_SEARCH
    done
    if [ -f "${SEARCH}.txt" ]
    then
        #echo "Trying $SEARCH"
        if [ "$DIVIDED" = 0 ]
        then
            NUMBER=$(($SEARCH + 0))
            echo "export NUMBMER=$NUMBER"
            exit
        fi
        increase_SEARCH
        test_SEARCH
    else
        #echo "Trying $SEARCH"
        if [ "$DIVIDED" = 0 ]
        then
            NUMBER=$(($SEARCH - 1))
            echo "export NUMBMER=$NUMBER"
            exit
        fi
        decrease_SEARCH
        test_SEARCH
    fi 
}

SEARCH=2
while   [[ "$SEARCH" -le "$1" ]] ;
do
    SEARCH=$(($SEARCH * 2))
done
DIVIDED=$(($SEARCH / 2))

test_SEARCH
```

In order to test the script for all file numbers and guesses between 1 and 1000, I use the following command:

```
 rm *.txt ;for textfile in {1..1000} ; do touch $textfile.txt ; for guess in {1..1000} ; do eval $(./search.sh $guess) ; if [ $NUMBMER  != "$(($(ls|wc -l) - 1))" ] ; then echo "Script failed $textfile $guess $NUMBMER" ; exit ; else echo $textfile $guess; fi ; done ; done
```

This works ok, but changing the contents of the first brackets with {4..1000} crashes my Ubuntu 12.04 Bash shell. The command loops through the number 4 fine.

So what problem am I facing here?

Comment: So with `{1..1000}` it works fine but with `{4..1000}` it crashes?

Comment: Indeed, but the script loops through 4 fine when I use {1..1000}

Comment: It's pretty strange. Have you debugged it by, for example, looping `{1..5}` and echoing every single step?

Comment: Your test for $DIVIDED=0 looks wrong for an integer, maybe -eq ?

Comment: Also both increase_SEARCH and decrease_SEARCH result in $DIVIDED being halved? Is that correct? Surely one should result in it being doubled?

Comment: Try changing first line to "#!/bin/bash -xv" to debug.

Comment: Yes, cound't see anything unusual.

Comment: @ Mark Setchell - The script appears to be counting correctly, the problem is the line that I use to test it.

Comment: Why the `eval`? Why not just `./search.sh "$guess"`?

Comment: @ Charles Duffy: eval because this exports the answer from the script to the shell as a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You bash shell doesn't crash, it is simply doing what you told it to do. Take a look at the command you run straight on the shell ( I rewrote it for readability )

```
rm *.txt                                                                              

for textfile in {1..1000} ; do                                                            |    SEARCH=$(($SEARCH + $DIVIDED))
    touch $textfile.txt                                                                   |    DIVIDED=$(($DIVIDED / 2))
    for guess in {1..1000}; do                                                            |    #echo $DIVIDED
        eval $(./search.sh $guess) <-- script run as subprocess                                                      |}
        if [ $NUMBMER  != "$(($(ls|wc -l) - 1))" ]; then                                  |
            echo "Script failed $textfile $guess $NUMBMER"                                |decrease_SEARCH()

            exit <---- this is terminating your shell                                                                        |{
        else                                                                              |    SEARCH=$(($SEARCH - $DIVIDED))
            echo $textfile $guess                                                         |    DIVIDED=$(($DIVIDED / 2))
        fi                                                                                |    #echo $DIVIDED
    done                                                                                  |}
done
```

When you invoke a bash script, it is run as a child process and as such, if you call `exit` within the script, you just terminate the subprocess.

When you run your command straight from the prompt, it is not run as a subprocess and as such when `exit` is called, it terminates your session.

So just remove `exit` from the command you run from the prompt to continue.

Comment: Yes, and this combined with the first blunder of assuming that starting with 4.txt without 1.txt etc. could be used to test the script caused the impression of a crash. Embarrassing.

Comment: It happens to all of us haha. :)